# jOOQ .fetchMap() with Converters

Tags: java, dictionary, converters, jooq

I am trying to execute .fetchMap(key, value) with jOOQ but I want to process the key through a custom converter.

The docs are very clear on how to use converters and how to use .fetchMap() but I can't find anywhere a way of combining both.

Could this feature be missing from my jOOQ version (3.9) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Converter`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/) (and [`Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/katest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/)) implementations are bound to the [`Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html) reference by the code generator, or you can do it manually like this:

```java
// Using this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Assuming a VARCHAR column in the database:
DataType<MyType> type = SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(
    new MyConverter<String, MyType>());
Field<MyType> field = field(name("MY_TABLE", "MY_FIELD"), type);
```

Now, whenever you fetch this `field` in your `SELECT` statements, e.g.

```java
Result<Record1<MyType>> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field)
   .from(...)
   .fetch();
```

jOOQ will automatically apply your converter while fetching results from the underlying JDBC `ResultSet`. You will never see the original `String` value in your result.

The [`ResultQuery.fetchMap(Field, Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) method that you've mentioned is just short for `fetch()` and then [`Result.intoMap(Field, Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#intoMap-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-). In other words, the converter will already have been applied automatically by the time you call `fetchMap()` or `intoMap()`, so there is no need to do anything specific. Just use your field as an argument to `fetchMap()` :

```java
Map<MyType, OtherType> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field, otherField)
   .from(...)
   .fetchMap(field, otherField);
```

Comment: can you shed some light on what method/functions are being used in ``field(name("MY_TABLE", "MY_FIELD"), type)``?  What are field() and name()?

Comment: @awm: Sure, I added the implied static import to the answer